# markdown not turning into a hyperlink

Tags: support, hyperlinks, wikipedia

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5229d936-d8fd-4dcb-967f-567ef3f527e9/view-source

For some reason my `[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller)` markup doesn't turn into a hyperlink on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209414/c-progamming-enter-3-characters-and-print-in-reverse-order/6209527#6209527). Other instances of this style of adding external links worked fine in my answer. I tried fiddling with line breaks but even when the entire content is on a single line, the hyperlink never renders.

I use the `[foo](URL)` markup all the time, so I'm surprised that this specific case doesn't render as I expect.

Comment: Sorry for updating it, but I figured you wanted a working link for your answer to be more meaningful which works fine using the [][] url syntax

Comment: @davidsleeps, heh, I really dislike keeping track of numbers for URLs manually, so I'll never go to the effort of writing one that way myself, but thanks for fixing my post. :)

Comment: I still think there is an issue that you described though perhaps...because the same formatted urls were working

Comment: Note that Firefox and now Chrome will both automatically encode such problem URLs for you when copying them out of the address bar. This is done *specifically because* so many sites have trouble dealing with the unencoded versions. So if you're using a browser that *doesn't* do this... Well, one more reason to stop hurting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Note that those are not dashes.

> `[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller)`
>   [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Not sure why Wikipedia insists on doing this, but the plain text ASCII equivalents always work.

> `[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)`
>   [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)

I believe inserting the link using the URL toolbar button, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> also works because it will encode the characters for you:

[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Yes, it does.

Comment: Wow. Crazy. Thanks Jeff, I never would have found _that_. Is there any point in trying to fix markup to Do The Right Thing when using copy-and-paste rather than menu-ey things?